# How to start the postgres 9.6 service on a docker centos 6 image

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I'm pretty new to docker-compose and I'm trying to build a container with postgres 9.6 on top of centos 6 and running it with docker compose up.
Then I want to be able to connect to the database through some db management tool.

If I run:

```
docker-compose up
```

- The image builds correctly but then I can't connect to the database.
- If I remove the **tty:true** and **stdin_open: true** the image builds but then it exits with exit code 0
- If I run docker-run -it -p 5432:5432 --entypoint /bin/bash [image_name] and then i run manually the command ***service postgresql-9.6 start*** everything works fine (until I exit the container).

Any suggestion?

Here's my docker-compose file:

```
networks{}
version: '2'
services:
    postgres:
        build:
          context: ./src/test/docker/postgres
        ports:
        - "5432:5432"
        stdin_open: true
        tty: true
```

And my docker file:

```
FROM centos:6

RUN yum -y install 
https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/9.6/redhat/rhel-6-x86_64/pgdg-
centos96-9.6-3.noarch.rpm

RUN yum -y install postgresql96 postgresql96-server postgresql96-libs 
postgresql96-contrib postgresql96-devel

# Initialize the database (not starting it yet)
RUN service postgresql-9.6 initdb

RUN su postgres

RUN echo "listen_addresses = '*'" >> /var/lib/pgsql/9.6/data/postgresql.conf
RUN echo "PORT = 5432" >> /var/lib/pgsql/9.6/data/postgresql.conf
RUN echo "local   all             all                                     trust" > /var/lib/pgsql/9.6/data/pg_hba.conf
RUN echo "host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            ident" >> /var/lib/pgsql/9.6/data/pg_hba.conf
RUN echo "host    all             all             ::1/128                 ident" >> /var/lib/pgsql/9.6/data/pg_hba.conf
RUN echo "host    all             all         0.0.0.0/0            md5" >> /var/lib/pgsql/9.6/data/pg_hba.conf

RUN exit

# Expose the PostgreSQL port
EXPOSE 5432

ENTRYPOINT service postgresql-9.6 start
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `ENTRYPOINT` in your docker file allows you to configure your container as an executable. It's a way of wrapping what you need run with all dependencies in a container and running the container = running your script/application etc.  See documentation details [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint)

Now your entry point

```
ENTRYPOINT service postgresql-9.6 start
```

Only runs the service start and exits! So your container will also exit. 
If you want to configure it like an executable you need to run the postgres command as your `ENTRYPOINT` command

```
  ENTRYPOINT ["sudo","-u","postgres","/usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/postgres","-D","‌​/var/lib/pgsql/9.6/d‌​ata","-p","5432"]
```

This will run postgres as your `ENTRYPOINT` command whenever the container starts, and you should be able to connect to it.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Colwin! your comment put me on the right path. I had to change just one paths in your command and run it as a "postgres" user. Please change it in your answer: ENTRYPOINT ["sudo","-u","postgres","/usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/postgres","-D","/var/lib/pgsql/9.6/data","-p","5432"]

Comment: Glad I could help @Sokrates. I have updated my answer with your new entry point. Can you please accept my answer if it helped solve your problem?

Comment: Hi @Colwin, I would like to, but it looks like I don't enough reputation to do that. Am I right?

Comment: You should be able to accept the answer no matter what your reputation level. Its the green checkmark under the voting buttons.

Comment: done thanks. If you feel my question make sense can you please upvote that as well?.